# Referencing Settings.settings and Resource.resx file from Class Library Project

Tags: c#, winforms, settings

In the past I've always referenced a `Settings.settings` and `Resources.resx` file in a Windows Forms project.  I was trying to move some code into their own projects one part of the code uses a settings and resource file to function.

I moved this code into a Class Library Project and now I'm having issues accessing the Settings and Resources that I've set.

Is it possible to have a Settings and Resource file in a class library?

If so is there anything special that needs to be done? (I can see and edit the properties in the Properties menu for the Project.

**EDIT:** Added Code

My using statements and example code...

```
using Data.Models;
using TSMTWin.Infrastructure;
using TSMTWin.Infrastructure.PDFCreation;
using PwObjectModel;
using Query;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;


//Usage example
if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) {
    Infrastructure.Properties.Settings.Default.HasToLogin = false;
    Infrastructure.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

I'm getting the red squiggly under the `Properties` property.

My app.config...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="Infrastructure.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <Infrastructure.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="QueryPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="HasSetIfHasToLogIn" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="HasToLogin" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </Infrastructure.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the Project Properties.  The Default Namespace is what is used (so it appears) when building the classes that return the values.

The Default Namespace needed to match the namespace of the file that I was trying to reference the settings from `internal` modifier is what was causing this.

Once all of these lined up the functionality returned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add resources and setting to class library. Just create a default settings/ resources in class lib project properties and try override this with your existing settings file. Look for namespace and other conflicts.

Comment: As referenced in the question.  I have already set the settings and resource files in the project.  Referencing them like I have in my Windows Forms project isn't functioning.